# How do I Sync data from client to server?

Tags: unity, networking, unity-networking

I'm trying to Sync data from the client to the server using the new Unity Networking, and I'm failing for some reason.

I've set up a prefab with a `NetworkIdentity` component with the attribute `Local Player Authority` set.

I (manually) spawn that on the server, and it is correctly propagated to the clients.

I have a couple of vars on this class, which the client sets and the server should read:

```
public class PlayerController : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SyncVar] public bool engineOn;
    [SyncVar] public Quaternion lookAt;
```

The client correctly sets them, however the server never receives them, they always stay at the default value.

What might be happening?

Comment: _The alternative is using `Command`, but I would like to understand if I can get it to work using `SyncVar`._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[SyncVar]` only sends messages from the server to the client.
You need `[Command]`.

Comment: You confirm this is also true even for objects with `Local Player Authority`?

Comment: PS: why the downvote?

Comment: Yes, I tested it on my cumputer and checked online document even if with **Local Player Authority**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this has been figured out or but here goes. I dropped the [SyncVar] portion except for health and shields on players and used the following code to get by break lights to sync across network.

```
void LateUpdate () {

    if (isLocalPlayer) {
        if (Input.GetButton ("Fire1")) {
            breakLightsOnOff = true;
        } else {
            breakLightsOnOff = false;
        }
        CmdBLC (breakLightsOnOff);
    }
}

[Command]
void CmdBLC(bool OnOff) {
    RpcBreakLightControl (OnOff);
}

[ClientRpc]
void RpcBreakLightControl(bool OnOff) {
    breakLights.SetActive (OnOff);
}
```

Comment: This was a huge help for me as I was using Command methods and SyncVars but hadn't used Rpc methods

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that Server will never receive these updates unless there is a LocalClient
on the machine running the server. Refer unity docs for the word **Host** i.e. Sever and a Client

Comment: So, local authority has no effect on syncvars? That would be very counter-intuitive…

Comment: The intension was to be able to turn any Single Player Game to Multiplayer in a few hours. If there is a client on the Server as well, one does not have to write special code for remote client and local client. It may be Counter-Intuitive but it is Productive. This way games can have dedicated servers.